# Maintaining application/system accounts for database access

Tags: sql, authentication, informix

(rephrased...)

How do you manage 'application' database accounts that have to follow the same policy as regular login-capable user accounts.

We have many processes in our system that run, unattended all the time, or part of scheduled jobs that need to access the database (Informix).  These have been, up until now, nologin/noexpire accounts.  We're now required to treat them as normal user accounts and their password to expire normally.

How do you manage/synchronize applications authenticating against the database when the credentials will at some point change?

We *could* generate a password based on the month, but since work is getting pushed through the system 24/7, that would likely lockout the account for too many failed attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two questions:

1. Are the applications (processes) running on the same machine as IDS?
2. Are they run by a process with the application account ID, or are they run by some administrative user (such as 'root') and the connection to the database specifies user name and password?

The answers are important because if the process is running on the local machine (the same machine as IDS) and the program is running as the 'application user', then the connection does not require a password at all.  So, the expiry/change of the passwords would not affect the database system at all.

If the applications are run on the same machine but are started by 'root', then an option is to modify the code that runs the applications so that where it now does:

```
run_application
```

in future it does:

```
su app_user -c run_application
```

User 'root', of course, is empowered to run things as other users without bothering with trivial details like passwords.  You might have to modify the application to avoid connecting with user name and password, again.

If the applications are not run on the same machines as IDS, the options are trickier.  There are ways to achieve this effect; you probably do not want to exercise them.
*(Contact me offline if you need details.  I will need some more details from you, too.  See my profile.)*

Comment: We have a mixed environment, some are on the same machine as the IDS instance, some not.